# Simultaneously Work on Packages of the Same Name

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm simultaneously working on two projects with the same starting-point code: I've forked public repo A twice locally. I want to publish my modifications to A (let's call this A') to open-source my code. However, I want to make different changes to the same original package and just use those locally (let's call this A").

Obviously, when I call "catkin_make", I get an error for having multiple packages of the same name. Is there a way around this? Should I setup multiple catkin workspaces or is this bad practice? Do I have to systematically go through one of the packages and change every duplicate name to something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239058/simultaneously-work-on-packages-of-the-same-name/) by [sbloch](https://answers.ros.org/users/27427/sbloch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having two different workspaces or renaming one of the variants of your package are the two most obvious solution to your problem. Both are reasonable; which one you choose really depends on why you have two copies of this package, and how you want to use them.

If your private version is making massive changes to the package or changing its functionality, it probably makes sense to rename it.

If you want to run nodes from both versions of the package at the same time, you should rename your private version.

If your private version will never be used at the same time as the open-source version, you can use it in a different catkin workspace without renaming it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To rename a ROS package:

1.Simply rename its folder name.

2.Update the name in Package.xml file of the package.

3.Update the name in CMakeLists.txt file of the package.

Its Done, No need to build that package again after renaming.

---

Originally posted by [YugalSharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/49911/yugalsharma/) with karma: 21 on 2020-03-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2